# ResultsController to another ResultsController

Tags: objective-c, xcode, uitableview, nsfetchedresultscontroller

CoreData and ResultsController make the job really easy. But...

Here is the situation:

I have a functional resultsController in one tableView. When selecting a row, I go to another tableView that will show the child entity. With coreData, the child entity is ready to use. But how do I start another resultsController with this child entity? Do I need to fetchRequest again for this new resultsController using predicate to filter?

Parent TablewView: Select row on resultsController
-> Child TableView: init from entity received and init another resultsController
 -> Desc of Child TableView: show detail from the row selected on the second RC.

Is there a better way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your second UITableView is just presenting the detail of 1 NSManagedObject, why create a resultsController.  Pass a pointer to the NSManagedObject to the new TableView and handle it's displaying in the `UITableViewDataSource` [protocol method](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UITableViewDataSource_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/intf/UITableViewDataSource).
You may want to order the element you want for each row in a NSArray, for shorter `- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath` implementation.
The NSArray must be done before the TableView first try to display itself.

Comment: But will the second UITableView present the changes made on the Detail UIView? For instance: First UITableView presents recipes, the second presents the ingredients, the third (An UIView) will present ingredient's details. If I change the ingredient name, will the second UITableView present this without a direct resultsController?

Comment: @pablotj if you are passing around the NSMagnagedObject, if you do modification on it and save the change into the context, when you go back to a UITableView controller it should reload it's data, if it don't reload you can force it to reload in viewWillAppear.

Comment: But I will lose the memory control that ResultsControlller gives. Is it possible to init a resultsController from another RS, or the only way to do that is the usual init?

Comment: @pablotj you will have to make a new one from scratch.