# Are the accessor methods created by to-many relationships as good as NSFetchedResultsControllers?

Tags: ios, uitableview, core-data, nsfetchedresultscontroller

My question is similar this one here:

[ResultsController to another ResultsController](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8736692/resultscontroller-to-another-resultscontroller)

A typical app structure on ios is to drill down into data via table views, and plenty of app models are hierarchical.  For example, a Film Festival could have many Films, which could have many Screenings, which could have many Attendees.  If we use Core Data to represent this model, then we can use an `NSFetchedResultsController` to populate Films into a `UITableView`.  Using the `NSFetchedResultsController` helps greatly with performance and memory efficiency, and provides built-in support for observing changes to the underlying data.  I would like to take advantage of this in my project as much as I can.

So if we have a table of Films backed by this sweet `NSFetchedResultsController`, and the user selects a Film to see a list of its Screenings, we can pass that Film (a subclass of `NSManagedObject`) to a new `UITableViewController` and populate that table with the film's screenings.

The core of my question is not "How do I do this?"  Instead, it's asking if the benefits of `NSFetchedResultsController` travel along with the `NSManagedObject`.  I could build a new results controller using the event in the predicate, but I don't need to.  If I pass the Film object into a variable called `film`, and my to-many relationship is identified as `screenings`, then I believe I can get the set of screenings related to that film like this:

```
NSSet *filmScreenings = [film screenings];
```

If I turn that set into an array, and use that as the data backing my new table view of screenings, am I losing the benefits of the `NSFetchedResultsController`?  My gut tells me yes, especially the support for monitoring changes - but an FAQ in Apple's docs made me second guess and ask the community at large.  Check out the question [in this FAQ](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CoreData/Articles/cdFAQ.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40001802-242985) called "I have a to-many relationship from Entity A to Entity B..."

Should I use that accessor method then, or should I build a new `NSFetchedResultsController`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will lose the benefits of `NSFetchedResultsController` by doing this (e.g. batch fetching and change monitoring), as you're going to replace it with a simple `NSArray`. You're best bet is to pass your `Film` to the details controller, and construct an `NSFetchedResultsController` using this `Film` in the predicate for the `NSFetchRequest`.

Comment: This is exactly what I ended up doing, and will only use the accessor methods on smaller sets of data that don't need to be so optimized.  Thanks for the straight answer!